# Connecting to Oracle database with ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, oracle-spatial, connection

I installed ArcGIS 10.2.2 ,oracle 11g R2 personal edition and it's client.I try to connect to the database using database connection in ArcMap but the error

> Failed to connect to the specified server. Do you want to continue?
>   Cannot connect to database because the database client software failed
>   to load. Be sure the database client software is installed and
>   configure correctly.

raised when i want to connect . How to solve the problem ?

[image]

Comment: It is not evident whether you have tried anything to answer your own question prior to posting.  Remember from the [help/on-topic] that "**We are not a GIS Software Support Site**. We encourage you to seek official routes for support for specific issues you may have."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ArcGIS is 32-bit, you will also have to make sure to install the ORACLE 32-bit client.

If you have installed the right version and it doesn't work, I'd contact someone who can give support on the ORACLE part.